# C++ Project migration from XE8 to 10.2 Tokyo

Tags: c++, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have to migrate a project written in C++ in an XE8 environment to the 10.2 Tokyo environment.

I will only substitute that I use additional PostgresDAC libraries to communicate with the Postgres database. In the XE8 version I used PostgresDAC controls in the older version and now at 10.2 Tokyo I use newer controls.

After solving the first problems with component paths, I still get errors related to PostgresDAC controls. I suspect that this is related to the fact that now I am using newer controls.

The content of the error:

> Unable to open include file 'PSQLDbTables.hpp'.

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error, I came to a solution.

It was enough to remove the reference to this file and re-compile the project.
The compiler dropped the link back and the errors disappeared.